# TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined when using image() in p5.js

Tags: javascript, image, p5.js

So I'm trying to show an image that I have loaded with `loadImage()`, but when i get to using the `image()` function I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Here is the code:

```
let img

function preLoad() {
  font = loadFont('../addons/Fonts/monof55')
  img = loadImage('./yes.jpg')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1200, 600)
  background('darkblue')

  fill('#EEEEEE')
  stroke(25)
  strokeWeight(2)
  rect(0, height - height / 20, width, height / 20)
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: what does logging `img` before `image()` output?

Comment: undefined, but I don't get how, as the image is called yes.jpg and its in the same folder as the code

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't loaded, because the function `preLoad()` is not executed.
It has to be [`preload()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) instead. JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the problem, but now i get
```p5.min.js:3 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/oof/Desktop/p5/addons/Fonts/monof55' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.```

Comment: For p5 to load images for you they have to be served over any of these protocols, not `file://`, so you have to set up a webserver.

Comment: So how would I change that?

Comment: Is your project intended to be served on a webserver?

Comment: This is how p5 recommmends running a local webserver: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server but maybe your IDE supports running a webserver itself, which IDE are you using?